# Can't donwload shapely package

Tags: python, pip, shapely

I need to download shapely, but I always get an error.

At first I tried using:

```
pip install shapely
```

It did not work, so I searched for it on the internet, and I was told to go here to down load the file: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely and I downloaded the file called Shapely‑1.6.4.post1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl, as my windows is 64 bits and this was the latest one. I tried again and it did not work. What I found in this question(https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62925/why-is-shapely-not-installing-correctly) told me to try this:

```
pip install Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64
```

It also did not work, but the error message was different.

Here are the error messages I got:

```
C:\Users\João Pedro>pip install Shapely
Collecting Shapely
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/fb/7a7af9ef7a35d16fa23
b127abee272cfc483ca89029b73e92e93cdf36e6b/Shapely-1.6.4.post2.tar.gz
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1wjtbq19\Shapely\se
tup.py", line 80, in <module>
        from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
      File "C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1wjtbq19\Shapely\sh
apely\_buildcfg.py", line 200, in <module>
        lgeos = CDLL("geos_c.dll")
      File "c:\users\joão pedro\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ctype
s\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: [WinError 126] Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1wjtbq19\Shapely\






C:\Users\João Pedro>pip install Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64
ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64'






C:\Users\João Pedro>python -m pip install Downloads\Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
WARNING: Requirement 'Downloads\\Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
ERROR: Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a valid wheel filename.






C:\Users\João Pedro>pip install Downloads\Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
WARNING: Requirement 'Downloads\\Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
ERROR: Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a valid wheel filename.
```

I also have the geos module, because in the PyPI page i says that you need it to have shapely installed.

Comment: `cd` into your Downloads folder and `pip install Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify the full path to the wheel file `Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` in the install command and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure  you download the right wheel for your Python version, cp37 won't work on any other Python version than 3.7. Also locate the destionation where Python is installed, navigate to venv->scripts and copy the whl there. Then cd to the same location and pip install that wheel.